# How to make a regular expression with floating point and constraint?

Tags: regex

How to make a regular expression that allows a floating-point number from -29999984 to 29999983?

I already have a regular expression that skips a floating point number:

```
[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)
```

it remains only to impose restrictions on it

I would like to see such a regular expression in which I could substitute any minimum number and any maximum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found the answer:

```
(^[+-]?0*[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+$)|(^[+-]?0*1[0-9]{7}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+-]?0*2[0-8][0-9]{6}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+-]?0*29[0-8][0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+-]?0*299[0-8][0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+-]?0*2999[0-8][0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+-]?0*29999[0-8][0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+-]?0*299999[0-7][0-9](\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^\-0*2999998[0-3](\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+]?0*2999998[0-2](\.[0-9]*)?$)|"^\-0*29999984(\.[0]*)?$)|(^[+]?0*29999983(\.[0]*)?$)
```